# How to solve the problem that only one character can be received after send in CSocket

Tags: c++, mfc

Some strings are sent, but the receiver only receives the first character of the string each time. What's the problem?

```
CSocket m_Socket;
if (m_Socket.Create())
{
    if (m_Socket.Connect(strIP, nPort))
    {
        int iSendLen = m_Socket.Send(m_strSendData, m_strSendData.GetLength() * 2);
    }
}
```

Comment: Recommendations: Use a packet analyzer to confirm you really are sending all the data you think you are sending. Add the receiver code to the question. Consider manufacturing a [mre], and if making the MRE doesn't end prematurely because you spot and fix the mistake, add the MRE to the question.

Comment: Showing some relevant code of the receiver side might help us to provide an answer.

Answer (score 2):

`CSocket` sends and receives arbitrary bytes, it has no concept of strings. You did not provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), but it is pretty obvious from your description that you are likely:

- sending the string data in UTF-16LE format (as evident by you multiplying the string length x2 to get a byte length), where ASCII characters `< 0x80` will be separated by nul bytes, eg: `"Hello"` in UTF-16LE is bytes `48 00 65 00 6C 00 6C 00 6F 00`.
- treating the received bytes as an 8bit/ANSI null-terminated string, thus terminating on the 1st nul byte, which is likely after the 1st received "character".

You need to normalize the format you use to send and receive strings.  Consider using UTF-8, for instance.